# stats - limiting distribution of $X_i$

Tags: probability, statistics, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose $P(X_{n}=i) = \frac{n+i}{3n+3},$ for $i = 0, 1, 2$. Find the limiting distribution of $X_{n}$.

Is the cdf $F_{x_{n}}$ like: " 
 if x = 0, $F_{x_{n}} = \frac{n}{3n+3}$;
 if x = 1, $F_{x_{n}} = \frac{n+1}{3n+3}$;
 if x = 2, $F_{x_{n}} = \frac{n+2}{3n+3}$; 
 if x > 2, $F_{x_{n}} = 1$;
 otherwise, $F_{x_{n}} = 0$ "?

Answer (score 0):

If by 'limiting distribution' you mean $\pi_i = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n=i)$ just take the limit $n \to \infty$ of the expression you have. What do you get?

Comment: You get f(x) = 1/3 in that case. So... does that mean that X is uniform 0 < x < 3? That doesn't seem right - why would they state i = 0,1,2?

Comment: you mean $0 \leq i < 3$, yes. Why doesn't it seem right?